# Why the input is locked after componentDidUpdate in TextInput of React Native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a screen with TextInput in React Native app. And when the default value of TextInput is changing, I call componentDidUpdate lifecycle:

```
public componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.login) {
  this.vm.loginOnChange(this.props.login);
  }
}
```

After it is not possible to edit the value in TextInput:

```
<TextInput 
  value={this.props.login}
  onChange={this.props.loginOnChange}
/>
```

It looks like the change of input value is locked. onChange event is working, but it is not possible to change the value. Can somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what does `loginOnChange` do? where you declare `login`? my best guess that you modify state with `loginOnChange` in a way that overwrites `login` state somehow incorrectly

Comment: it is not doing something special, just take a value and set state: loginOnChange = (value) => { this.setState({login: value})}

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, but it is not working for me, i think have this, because providing a value on TextInput. it is was described here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value

Comment: but I don't know how to solve it (((

Answer (score 1):

It must be not working, it looks so wired. If you want to achieve something like that, you could use like this:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: "" }; //declare a state named text
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.login!== prevProps.login) {
      this.setState({ text: this.props.login });//if this.props.login just true or false , put your text instead(and change the condition as you want), then setstate to update new text
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
          onChangeText={textchange => this.setState({ text:textchange })} //control the text value
          value={this.state.text} //receive the text with state change will update
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Follow the [example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.56/textinput) will be more easier.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I tried, but it is not working (((

Comment: componentDidUpdate will trigger from other scene navigate to this scene with props, maybe it's the problems from, how do you parse `this.props.login`?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in componentDidUpdate, I made this:

```
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
    if (!!this.props.login && this.props.login !== prevProps.login) {
      this.loginOnChange(this.props.login);
    }
  }
```

And now it works!